# Timer Interval Is Smaller Than Function In Tick Event

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a `timer` with 10 seconds `interval` and on `timer_Tick` event I do some stuff which usually needs about a second, but sometimes it needs More than 90 seconds. How will it act? Is this  event synchronous to wait for the `eventhandler` to finish executing? I tested but still I need an answer...

```
private void checkTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Test");   
    for (int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++)
    {

    }
    MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

when i test it after first tick `MessageBox` is shown. **I don't click OK** and wait for another tick. And another `MessageBox` is shown on the seconds tick and so on...

in [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) I read that it is synchronous... Any Idea?

Comment: RTM. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Comment: what task are you actually performing inside the timer_tick? can you give the code?

Comment: Where did you read that it is synchronous?  I can't see on the page you linked where this is mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by adding timer disabling at the beginning of tick event and enabling at the end of tick event. like this

```
private void checkTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkTimer.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("Test");   
            for (int i = 0; i < 2000000000; i++)
            {

            }
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
            checkTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing in the `System.Windows.Timers` Documentation that you linked to that mentions it being synchronized. If you want each Tick event to wait to the previous Tick Event has finished. Stop the Timer at the start of your handler and restart in after your work is done. That is what the MSDN documentation shows.

Comment: Yes it is. I left my answer to clarify that there is nothing in the documentation that mentions the event being synchronized